# Who is responsible for a compromised computer?

Tags: legal, system-compromise

In light of the recent public hacks on public systems, is there any culpability for the owner of a compromised system? Two examples:

1. The owner is a large public company that leaks sensitive information through a malicious hack (for arguments sake, assume it came from the outside).
2. Your personal computer unknowingly participates in a DOS attack through a botnet.

Both of these carry legal penalties if they were committed knowingly. To make this question concrete and not subjective, *"is there legal precedent in the US, either for or against, concerning the culpability for the owner of a hacked computer?"*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is requesting legal advice, which not only may vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction but also from case to case, and so should be obtained from a qualified legal practitioner in the appropriate jurisdiction rather than from the Internet where the well-meaning and logical opinions you receive on the matter may leave you more ill-advised than if you hadn't asked at all.

Comment: The question is also pretty broad. There are numerous responsibilities: to prevent damage, to limit damage, to disclose damage. There are also overlapping legal, regulatory, and civil responsibilities depending on the jurisdiction.

Comment: @Xander I am not seeking legal advice, I was wondering if there was legal precedent concerning this particular issue of information security. It can be made clear in any answer that this is simply a factual response to a question concerning events that have either happened or not. I would be happy with a reference and an excerpt from the ruling with the caveat that the interpretation is left to the reader.

Comment: I believe it's still off-topic, as it's legal rather than technical. If you're looking for a precedent, it _might_ be on-topic on [History.SE].

Comment: @S.L.Barth understood, and as an outsider to this Stack Exchange I would completely understand the motivation behind a close (and respect the decision!). It is unfortunate though, that there isn't a good forum for this kind of question, it _is_ related to information security, but to make the question non-subjective I had to restrict it to a legal question.

Comment: @Hooked While it is an interesting question, the issue is that likely no one here has the necessary qualifications to answer it. While we could make guesses about what would happen, they'd pretty much just be guesses.